# How to add ajax pagination in Joomla2.5 module?

Tags: ajax, joomla2.5

I need to do pagination for video content displaying in front-end in joomla 2.5. How to add ajax pagination in Joomla2.5 module?

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own? Have you done any research on Ajax based modules? Lots of developers are struggling to get Ajax working with their modules as it is much harder than components using it. Try some things of your own then show us what you have tried.

Comment: Actually i tried by applying carousel for displaying the videos and find its working fine. I have to put pagination for that carousel, for that i searched in google but i cant found the code to put pagination in joomla module. Can you help me to put pagination in joomla module.